# an encoding issue while generating beamer slides in rmarkdown

Tags: rstudio, r-markdown, knitr, beamer

I am testing to generate Beamer presentations using Rmarkdown in Rstudio. 
Everything works fine, but an error below appears and fail to generate Beamer slides when a few Korean words are added into the code. Generating html(ioslides, slidy) works fine with the Korean words, but only converting to Beamer presentation encounters the error.
I searched some posts and tested suggested solutions, but none of them worked; Neither saving the file with UTF-8 encoding nor adding the code below works.

```
latex_engine: xelatex
```

My OS is Windows 10 which is set to Korean. Any comments would be appreciated.

```
---
title: "Habits"
author: "John Doe"
date: "March 22, 2005"
output:
  beamer_presentation: default
encoding: UTF-8
---

# 오전 

## Getting up

- Turn off alarm
- Get out of bed
```

> "C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS
>   1-example.utf8.md --to beamer --from
>   markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash
>   --output 1-example.tex --highlight-style tango --latex-engine pdflatex --self-contained  output file: 1-example.knit.md
>
> ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character 오 (U+C624) (inputenc)
>   not set up for use with LaTeX.
>
> Error: Failed to compile 1-example.tex. See 1-example.log for more
>   info. In addition: Warning message: In grepl("==> Fatal error
>   occurred", x[i], fixed = TRUE) :   input string 1 is invalid in this
>   locale Execution halted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`latex_engine` is an argument of `beamer_presentation` (see [Section 3.3.7.1 of the R Markdown book](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/pdf-document.html#advanced-customization-1)).

```
---
title: "Habits"
author: "John Doe"
date: "March 22, 2005"
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{kotex-utf}
output:
  beamer_presentation:
    latex_engine: xelatex
---

# 오전 

## Getting up

- Turn off alarm
- Get out of bed
```

The `encoding` option in your example is not meaningful to either Pandoc ro **rmarkdown**.

Comment: Thanks, but latex_engine: xelatex does not work as well. This is the error I got. 

Error in yaml::yaml.load(string, ...) : 
  Scanner error: mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 6, column 17
Calls: <Anonymous> ... parse_yaml_front_matter -> yaml_load_utf8 -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted

Comment: Did you run an _exact_ copy of my example?

Comment: At first, your code didn't work. But I updated MiKTex and tried it again. This time, it generated beamer slides, but the Korean word appeared only on the bookmark, not on the beamer slides. Then, I added "header-includes:
  - \usepackage{kotex-utf}" and got the result I wanted. Please refer to the link  https://github.com/yufree/democode/tree/master/cjk
Thank you for your time and help!